# Javascript Error al mostrar objeto con console.log

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo creado el siguiente objeto creado en una función de un fichero javascript, a la que llamo desde un botón de formulario

```
<form action="">
   <button id="boton" onclick="arranca();">Click</button>
</form>


function arranca(){
    var datos = {
        ip_address : "1.1.1.1",
        comentario : "",
        nombre_objeto : "sh1"
    }
    console.log(datos);
}
```

a la hora de imprimir en la consola me aparece el siguiente mensaje

> Object { ip_address: "1.1.1.1", comentario: "", nombre_objeto: "sh1" }
>
> Error en el mapeo fuente: Error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch
> resource. URL del recurso:
> moz-extension://a63c3158-1016-4295-8b1d-970a1f95f27e/browser-polyfill.min.js
> URL del mapa fuente: browser-polyfill.min.js.map

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven, al desplegar el objeto no me deja ver el contenido.

¿Alguna idea del porqué de este error?

Comment: Parece un problema de alguna extensión que tengas instalada. Te recomiendo que revises las extensiones instaladas, puedes probar a deshabilitarlas e ir habilitando una a una hasta que veas que se vuelve a reproducir el problema, así sabrás cual es la causante.

Answer (score 0):

Hay ciertas cosas que se hacen de forma automática, en este caso, cuando pones un botón dentro de un form, automáticamente, este botón se convierte a tipo "submit", cuando le das clic a un botón tipo submit este ejecuta la acción del formulario, esta acción suele ser una url que se encuentra en la propiedad "action" del formulario, si no pones nada o pones una url que no está preparada para recibir este formulario te aparecerá un error, hay un par de formas de evitar esto

opción 1: definir el tipo de los botones:

```
<form action="">
 <button type="button">
 click me
 </button>
</form>
```

opción 2: prevenir la acción "submit" por defecto del botón

```
<form action="">
 <button onclick="buttonClicked(event)">
 click me
 </button>
</form>

function buttonClicked(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```